# How To Install Git Daemon on Ubuntu 10.04 Linux with SparkleShare (and use it like Drop Box)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, daemon, git

I tried following this doc...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git

...but unfortunately the "initialKeyFileName" step is not explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says on the top:

> - You already have a public ssh key on your local machine you can use that to initialize the repository. Don't have one? [Look here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Generating+RSA+Keys).

The linked article is great, should be no problem to follow it.

Comment: Wow. I missed that. Need to slow down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Sparkle Share – Git server   installation in Ubuntu 10.04

I am starting with an empty Ubuntu server 10.04 with just openssh installed. I assuming that you can access you server from http://mydomain.com

Install Git

```
aptitude build-dep git-core
apt-get install git-core
git --version   #(not necessary just to insure that is installed)
```

Add user git

```
adduser --disabled-password git
git init --bare /home/git/MyProject  #(your projects folder, named as you like)
```

Make a key file in order to login without a password

```
mkdir /home/git/.ssh
touch /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Edit file `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` and paste your key. You can find it your projects file as .txt file at The client side.

```
pico /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Change owner and permissions on files

```
chmod 700 /home/git/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R git:git /home/git
```

Add your server in client

```
mydomain.com      ,        /home/git/MyProject
```

Answer (score 0):

I've create a document [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-a-public-git-repository-on-a-debian-server) about install git on Debian box, i think that you may follow the same step on a Ubuntu